# React componentDidUpdate not receiving latest props

Tags: reactjs, redux

In Redux, I'm running the following in a redux-thunk action creator:

```
dispatch({type: "CASCADING_PROMPT_STATUS", promptName, list: 'model', status: 'disabled'});
dispatch({type: "CASCADING_PROMPT_STATUS", promptName, list: 'model', status: 'enabled'});
```

This triggers the reducer twice, and I can see in the console that Redux state changes from disabled -> enabled.

In React, I have the following component which has props connected to state of which CASCADING_PROMPT_STATUS updates.

However, in my component, I'm running a check to see if state changed in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)`

This doesn't trigger.

If I change the action creator to delay the second dispatch `setTimeout(<dispatch...>, 1);` even by one millisecond, prevProps !== this.props, which is what I expect.

My component is connected to redux like so:

```
const C_Component = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {pure: false})(Component);
```

Does React batch up prop changes? Why do I have to delay the second dispatch? I thought redux dispatch were synchronous.

Edit: The way I'm updating the redux state is as follows:

```
var newState = {};

if (!_.isUndefined(state)){
    newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
}
...
    case "CASCADING_PROMPT_STATUS":
        newState[action.promptName][action.list].disable = action.status === 'disabled';
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Redux dispatches are synchronous (unless a middleware intercepts and delays the action).  However, React updates are batched in most cases.

Second, your reducer is definitely mutating the state, because you're not copying *every* level of nesting that needs to be updated.  The mutations will cause your connected component to think nothing has changed, and skip updating.  See the [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section of the docs for more details on how to properly do immutable updates.

Actually... re-reading your reducer, you *are* doing a deep clone, so in theory that's not mutating.  However, per the Redux FAQ, [deep cloning is a bad idea](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-clone-state).  Instead, you should do *nested shallow updates*.

Third, your `shouldComponentUpdate` shouldn't compare `this.props` vs `nextProps` themselves.  The actual props objects themselves will definitely be different.  Instead, it should compare the *contents* of those objects - ie, `props.a !== nextProps.a && props.b !== nextProps.b`, etc.  This is known as a "shallow equality comparison".

Comment: If React updates are batched, is there a way to toggle state without purposefully delaying the second dispatch?

Comment: I'm not actually using `shouldComponentUpdate`, I'm using `componentDidUpdate` - shoud I be using the former?

Comment: @tgun926 What is the benefit of mutating the state just to mutate it again <1 ms afterwards? This is next to unnoticable for the user.

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is and what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: When the user selects an option on the first dropdown, another dropdown gets populated (not asynchronously, but filtering on a larger dataset). What I want to achieve is the second dropdown to automatically open when it's done populating. I do this in the component via checking if prevProps.disabled == true and currentProps.disabled == false in `componentDidUpdate`