# Function inside component not receiving latest version of Redux-state to quit polling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an issue where I am trying to use the Redux state to halt the execution of some polling by using the state in an `if` conditional. I have gone through posts of SO and blogs but none deal with my issue, unfortunately. I have checked that I am using mapStateToProps correctly, I update state immutably, and I am using Redux-Thunk for async actions. Some posts I have looked at are:

- [Component not receiving new props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284989/component-not-receiving-new-props)
- [React componentDidUpdate not receiving latest props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991957/react-componentdidupdate-not-receiving-latest-props)
- [Redux store updates successfully, but component's mapStateToProps receiving old state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754014/redux-store-updates-successfully-but-components-mapstatetoprops-receiving-old)

I was kindly helped with the polling methodology in this post:[Incorporating async actions, promise.then() and recursive setTimeout whilst avoiding "deferred antipattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594210/incorporating-async-actions-promise-then-and-recursive-settimeout-whilst-avoi) but I wanted to use the redux-state as a single source of truth, but perhaps this is not possible in my use-case.

I have trimmed down the code for readability of the actual issue to only include relevant aspects as I have a large amount of code. I am happy to post it all but wanted to keep the question as lean as possible.

```
Loader.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { delay } from '../../shared/utility'
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/index';

const Loader = (props) => {
  const pollDatabase = (jobId, pollFunction) => { 
    return delay(5000)
      .then(pollFunction(jobId))  
        .catch(err => console.log("Failed in pollDatabase function. Error: ", err))
        };

  const pollUntilComplete = (jobId, pollFunction) => { 
    return pollDatabase(jobId, pollFunction)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(props.loadJobCompletionStatus) // <- always null
            if (!props.loadJobCompletionStatus) { <-- This is always null which is the initial state in reducer
                return pollUntilComplete(jobId, pollFunction);
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log("Failed in pollUntilComplete. Error: ", err));
    };


  const uploadHandler = () => {
  ...
    const transferPromise = apiCall1() // Names changed to reduce code
      .then(res=> {
        return axios.post(api2url, res.data.id);
            })
      .then(postResponse=> {
        return axios.put(api3url, file)
        .then(()=>{ 
          return instance.post(api3url, postResponse.data) 
        })
      })

  transferDataPromise.then((res) => {
    return pollUntilComplete(res.data.job_id, 
      props.checkLoadTaskStatus)
        })
        .then(res => console.log("Task complete: ", res))
        .catch(err => console.log("An error occurred: ", err))
  }

return ( ...); // 

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        datasets: state.datasets,
        loadJobCompletionStatus: state.loadJobCompletionStatus,
        loadJobErrorStatus: state.loadJobErrorStatus,
        loadJobIsPolling: state.loadJobPollingFirestore
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    checkLoadTaskStatus: (jobId) => 
         dispatch(actions.loadTaskStatusInit(jobId))
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DataLoader);
```

```
delay.js
export const delay = (millis) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}
```

```
actions.js
...
export const loadTaskStatusInit = (jobId) => {
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch(loadTaskStatusStart()); // 
      const docRef = firestore.collection('coll').doc(jobId) 
        return docRef.get() 
        .then(jobData=>{
            const completionStatus = jobData.data().complete;
            const errorStatus = jobData.data().error;
            dispatch(loadTaskStatusSuccess(completionStatus, errorStatus))
        },
        error => {
            dispatch(loadTaskStatusFail(error));
        })
    };
}
```

It seems that when I console log the value of `props.loadJobCompletionStatus` is always null, which is the initial state of in my reducer. Using Redux-dev tools I see that the state does indeed update and all actions take place as I expected.

I initially had placed the `props.loadJobCompletionStatus` as an argument to  `pollDatabase` and thought I had perhaps created a  closure, and so I removed the arguments in the function definition so that the function would fetch the results from the "upper" levels of scope, hoping it would fetch the latest Redux state. I am unsure as to why I am left with a stale version of the state. This causes my if statement to always execute and thus I have infinite polling of the database.

Can anybody point out what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into redux sagas?

Comment: Yes I have used sagas. This code base was mainly written with thunk though. However, I am not so sure sagas would solve this issue. I think this is more related to trying to access an updated state in the same render.

Comment: I only asked as I've always moved any api related activity into sagas, and it's worked pretty well for me. You could use an effect to dispatch a single action (startPolling e.g.), which the saga would pick up, do the polling, dispatching actions to update state accordingly. I'd also look into the new hooks in react-redux, useSelector and useDispatch, saves you having to wrap your components with the connect hoc.

Comment: Hi @Matt thanks for that. I spent a couple hours re-reading the hooks documentation and I think I have come up with a few ways to overcome the issue. It would have been nice to put this into a Redux so that it persisted across all pages and I could dump the whole thing into local storage but I don't think my use case allows it. I agree that sagas is the way to go, especially with more complex and larger code bases in my opinion. I will be using that and/or some of the other hooks going forward for new projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because you are defining a closure in a function component, and thus the closure is capturing a reference to the existing props *at the time the closure was defined*.  See [Dan Abramov's extensive post "The Complete Guide to `useEffect`"](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to better understand how closures and function components relate to each other.

As alternatives, you could move the polling logic out of the component and execute it in a thunk (where it has access to `getState()`), or use the `useRef()` hook to have a mutable value that could be accessed over time (and potentially use a `useEffect()` to store the latest props value in that ref after each re-render).  There are probably existing hooks available that would do something similar to that `useRef()` approach as well.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have gone through the article. It was a a very insightful read. It definitely seems that because I am in the same render that I would not have access to the updated state, if I was using React hooks only. Do you know if the logic is the same for the Redux store? I am going to go through the useRef hook to see how it is used in this context.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter whether you're using a React hook or something Redux related - the code as written would be capturing the existing value at the time of render.  You need one of the alternate approaches / escape hatches I listed to work around that.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Makes perfect sense. I will have to bite the bullet and refactor some code. Appreciate the advice.